# redirect after .submit() form

Tags: jquery, forms, redirect, submit

I have a HTML form which uses a div (submitme) to trigger the following code.....the code then uses the bValidator plugin to validate the form fields and then checks whether a honeypot field is blank before submitting the form....

When I exclude the "window.location..." etc the .submit() works and posts the form through, however when including it; the validation/honeypot still works but no form submits.

Im new to JQUERY and was wondering if theres something simple im missing or a better way to write the below:

```
$("#submitme").click(function(){
    if($('#right-body-div').data('bValidator').validate()) {

        if ($("#honeypot").val() == "") {
                $('#pgpost').submit();
                window.location = "http://www.homepage.co.uk/thankyou";    
                return true;
              }
           window.location = "http://www.homepage.co.uk/nothankyou";
           return false;
    }
});
```

If possible id like to accomplish this without the use of AJAX/PHP.

Your thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't post and then redirect, you'd just post.  The server should respond to the post with the appropriate response.  A redirect isn't necessary because the act of posting refreshes to a new page.  You should post to the desired destination page and handle the server-side post on that.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#pgpost').submit(function(e) {  // this handles the submit event
    if($('#right-body-div').data('bValidator').validate()) {
        if ($("#honeypot").val() == "") {
            /*
             * url = $('#pgpost').val('action');
             * data = $('#pgpost').serialize();
             * $.post(url, data, function() {
             *     window.location = "http://www.homepage.co.uk/thankyou";
             * });
             */
            window.location = "http://www.homepage.co.uk/thankyou";
        }
        else {
            window.location = "http://www.homepage.co.uk/nothankyou";
        }
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    /*
     * the 2 lines above are meant to prevent the normal behaviour
     * that the <form> would have (which is to submit via browser).
     * 
     * e.preventDefault() is the jquery way prevent the normal behaviour
     * return false is the legacy way to do it, you can use either or both
     * 
     * the reason for which the code didn't validate your form is
     * that e.prevenDefault() was only called inside the IF statement
     * which means that it would only be called if the field was
     * already in valid form. So basically if the form was invalid the normal
     * behaviour is not prevented and the browser submits the form, if the form
     * was valid the submit behaviour was prevented and the redirect was used.
     * 
     */
});

$("#submitme").click(function(){
    $('#pgpost').submit(); // this triggers the submit event
});
```

When handling the submit event via JavaScript you can:

- prevent normal behaviour always (our case):

  - when form is valid you [submit the data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) via JavaScript and maybe you process it before submitting it;
  - when the form is invalid you show error messages;
- prevent normal behaviour only **when form is invalid**:

  - when the form is valid you allow normal behaviour (browser submits data);
  - when the form is invalid you show error messages;

Error messages in your case should state that honeypot is not supposed to be empty.

It makes sense to prevent normal behaviour if:
 - you need to process the data before it is sent to the server (creating new values, changing present values; **not validation**);
 - you need to avoid a page refresh so you send via AJAX;

Just for validation it doesn't make sense to prevent the behaviour, because you can validate then allow the normal behaviour to continue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response all,

Following Mihai's code, the removal of "return true" and addition of "else" on the second window.location the form now submits and redirects however the form now posts every time, even if the fields are not valid - in my original code the honeypot/submit would only run if the fields were valid (nested).

any further suggestions? (David thank you for your comment, I will look into your suggestion as will have to learn how to write the server-side handling and postback etc).

Comment: Thank you Mihai for taking the time to re-write the code & additional comments...the honeypot/validation now works and prevents the form from submitting, also the redirect works, sending the user to the correct page dependent on honeypot value, however the form does not seem to be submitting (nothing has changed with the PHP script handling the form and emailing to my inbox) so can only assume its something to do with the .submit().....any ideas?